# How to show or hide a textInput in R shiny depending on a radioButton choice?

Tags: r, shiny

In my reprex below, Number duplicates the inputs. I am stuck on how to achieve two things.

1. If the Contractor radio button option is selected, show a text input with label "Name of Contractor".
2. How can I have the radio button input set as empty? I know `selected = character(0)` achieves this, but it causes another challenge: if an option is selected, and then Number is changed, the radio button selection will disappear. In my reprex, the radio button selection will not be affected after Number is changed, but the default selection is the first choice, whereas I would like the default to be empty.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("n", "Number", value = 1),
  uiOutput("col")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Dynamic UI: Multiple Controls -------------------------------------------
  
  col_names <- reactive(paste0("staff_attended_", seq_len(input$n)))
  
  output$col <- renderUI({
    map(
      col_names(), 
      ~ tagList(
          selectInput(
            .x,
            label = "Staff Attended",
            choices = letters,
            selected = isolate(input[[.x]]),
            multiple = TRUE
          ),
          
          radioButtons(
            paste0(.x, "_type"), 
            "Staff Attended: Shift/Call-In/Contractor?",
            choices = c("Shift", "Call-In", "Contractor"),
            selected = isolate(input[[paste0(.x, "_type")]])
          )
          
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: How important is the radio button question? As you already saw the `character(0)` workaround, you may have seen that this it is not really state of the art to have something like this as discussed in some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772944/reset-radiobuttons-in-shiny-to-empty-value) questions. I managed to get question 1 to work but it even more complicates it with question 2. Would a `checkboxGroupInput` be an alternative?

Comment: Yes a `checkboxGroupInput` would be an alternative, or anything else that achieves the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example.

**Question 1:** *If the Contractor radio button option is selected, show a text input with label "Name of Contractor"*.

Therefore we can use a `conditionalPanel` which contains a `textInput`. The condition can be written as

```
paste0(
   "(document.querySelector('input[name=\"",
   .x,
   "_type\"]:checked') || {value: 'dummy'}).value === 'Contractor'"
)
```

Explanation:

- The `document.querySelector` call aims for the checked value of the
  `radioButtons`. The relevant checkbox id is assigned by `.x` inside
  your `map` call. It shall return `TRUE` if this value is "Contractor".
- Since you would like to have empty `radioButtons` when starting the app, the `querySelector` would be `null` while being in this state. Hence, the `|| {value: 'dummy'})` will yield a dummy value such that there won't be an error and the `textInput` is hidden by the start of the app. Otherwise, the `||` operator will short-circuit.

[image]

**Question 2:** *How can I have the radio button input set as empty? I know selected = character(0) achieves this, but it causes another challenge: if an option is selected, and then Number is changed, the radio button selection will disappear*...

In order to retain the selection when the number is changed, we put an `observeEvent` on `input$n` and use an `updateRadioButtons`, which will affect the `selected` parameter using `isolate`.

```
observeEvent(input$n, {
    map(col_names(),
        ~ tagList(
            updateRadioButtons(session, paste0(.x, "_type"),
                               selected = isolate(input[[paste0(.x, "_type")]]))
        ))
})
```

[image]

Complete minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(numericInput("n", "Number", value = 1),
                uiOutput("col"))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Dynamic UI: Multiple Controls -------------------------------------------
    
    col_names <-
        reactive(paste0("staff_attended_", seq_len(input$n)))
    
    observeEvent(input$n, {
        map(col_names(),
            ~ tagList(
                updateRadioButtons(session, paste0(.x, "_type"),
                                   selected = isolate(input[[paste0(.x, "_type")]]))
            ))
    })
    
    output$col <- renderUI({
        map(col_names(),
            ~ tagList(
                selectInput(
                    .x,
                    label = "Staff Attended",
                    choices = letters,
                    selected = isolate(input[[.x]]),
                    multiple = TRUE
                ),
                
                radioButtons(
                    paste0(.x, "_type"),
                    "Staff Attended: Shift/Call-In/Contractor?",
                    choices = c("Shift", "Call-In", "Contractor"),
                    selected = character(0)#isolate(input[[paste0(.x, "_type")]])
                ),
                
                conditionalPanel(
                    paste0(
                        "(document.querySelector('input[name=\"",
                        .x,
                        "_type\"]:checked') || {value: 'dummy'}).value === 'Contractor'"
                    ),
                    textInput("NameContractor", "Name of Contractor")
                )
                
            ))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```